# Workaround for safari's buggy rendering of inner SVG Animation?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-transitions

I'm looking for a workaround for safari's buggy rendering of inner SVG with CSS Animations.
[Here it is on codepen.](http://codepen.io/shakdaniel/pen/Pwmpzx)

Chrome does this perfectly well, but in Safari the transitioning within the animation doesn't render until it jumps between states.
What is causing it?

**Relevant CSS3**

```
.avatar {
  z-index: 800;
}
.avatar path {
  stroke: #e1afff;
  stroke-width: 0.15;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transition: all 6s ease;
  transition: all 6s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
  transform: translate(0);
}
.avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  -webkit-animation: p1 3s ease 1;
      animation: p1 3s ease 1;
}
.avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
  -webkit-animation: p2 3s ease 1;
      animation: p2 3s ease 1;
}
.avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
  -webkit-animation: p3 3s ease 1;
      animation: p3 3s ease 1;
}
.avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  -webkit-animation: p4 3s ease 1;
      animation: p4 3s ease 1;
}
.hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40vw;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  margin-top: -20vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-animation: waitforit 0 ease-in 3s 1 forwards;
      animation: waitforit 0 ease-in 3s 1 forwards;
}
.hover:hover + .avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(800%, 400%) rotate(-690deg) translateZ(0);
      transform: translate(800%, 400%) rotate(-690deg) translateZ(0);
}
.hover:hover + .avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-700%, 600%) rotate(-720deg) translateZ(0);
      transform: translate(-700%, 600%) rotate(-720deg) translateZ(0);
}
.hover:hover + .avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-900%, -500%) rotate(-820deg) translateZ(0);
      transform: translate(-900%, -500%) rotate(-820deg) translateZ(0);
}
.hover:hover + .avatar path:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(700%, -800%) rotate(-950deg) translateZ(0);
      transform: translate(700%, -800%) rotate(-950deg) translateZ(0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes p1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-300%, -700%) rotate(520deg) translateZ(0);
        transform: translate(-300%, -700%) rotate(520deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
        transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes p1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-300%, -700%) rotate(520deg) translateZ(0);
        transform: translate(-300%, -700%) rotate(520deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
        transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes p2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(400%, -900%) rotate(850deg) translateZ(0);
        transform: translate(400%, -900%) rotate(850deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
        transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes p2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(400%, -900%) rotate(850deg) translateZ(0);
        transform: translate(400%, -900%) rotate(850deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
        transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes p3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(500%, 900%) rotate(325deg) translateZ(0);
        transform: translate(500%, 900%) rotate(325deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
        transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes p3 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(500%, 900%) rotate(325deg) translateZ(0);
        transform: translate(500%, 900%) rotate(325deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
        transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes p4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-500%, 900%) rotate(748deg) translateZ(0);
        transform: translate(-500%, 900%) rotate(748deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
        transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes p4 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-500%, 900%) rotate(748deg) translateZ(0);
        transform: translate(-500%, 900%) rotate(748deg) translateZ(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
        transform: translate(0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes waitforit {
  0% {
    display: none;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
  }
}
@keyframes waitforit {
  0% {
    display: none;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

The vendor prefix -webkit- applies to both Chrome & Safari. Safari is known to be buggy in rendering inner SVG animations, however there is usually a happy medium. Can anyone think of a workaround of sorts? Maybe an easy js fix?

Comment: $10 PayPal to anyone who has a workaround.